# Nested Cursors Using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

I need help with my "`postgresql nested cursors"` code.

My plan is to get rows of data from a table (`Admissions`) using the "outer cursor" and evaluating each row using criteria from another table (`EventLog_Staging)`. After evaluating each row, I insert the result to a table (`EventLog_Main`).

The problem is, I am passing the value of a column from the returned record from the first cursor but my `INSERT` statement is not recognizing it.

**-- CURSOR CODE BLOCK TO CREATE AN EVENT LOG**

```
DO
$Event_Log_Creation_Code$
DECLARE
    rec_tbls RECORD;
    schem_name VARCHAR(100) := 'mimiciii';
    set_SrchPath text;
    tx text;
    tbl_name VARCHAR(50);
    tbl_column VARCHAR(50);
    col_datatype VARCHAR(50);
    event_role VARCHAR(50);
    life_cycle VARCHAR(50);

    csr_outer_create_evnt_log REFCURSOR; --Cursor to get the data from the main table
    csr_innner_create_evnt_log REFCURSOR; --Cursor to dissect each row of the main table    

    sql_eventlog_stge_rows text := 'SELECT tablename, columnname, datatype, eventrole, lifecycle 
            FROM EventLog_Staging  
            WHERE eventrole IS NOT NULL;';

    sql_table_rows text := 'Select * from admissions;';

   BEGIN

        -- Setting the search path to the specified db schema
        set_SrchPath := concat('SET search_path TO ',schem_name,';');
        EXECUTE set_SrchPath;


        -- Opening the outer cursor
        OPEN csr_outer_create_evnt_log FOR EXECUTE sql_table_rows;
        LOOP
            --Fetch rows into the specified fields
            FETCH csr_outer_create_evnt_log INTO rec_tbls; 
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;  

            -- Create inner cursor
            OPEN csr_innner_create_evnt_log FOR EXECUTE sql_eventlog_stge_rows;

            -- Opening the inner Loop
            LOOP 
                --Fetch rows into the specified fields
                FETCH csr_innner_create_evnt_log INTO tbl_name, tbl_column, col_datatype, event_role, life_cycle; 
                EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;       

                IF event_role = 'Event' THEN

                    tx :=concat('INSERT INTO EventLog_Main (case_id, activity, lifecycle, time_stamp)
                VALUES (',rec_tbls.hadm_id,',''',tbl_column,''',''',life_cycle,''',',rec_tbls.tbl_column,');');

                    EXECUTE tx;

                END IF;    

            --Closing the inner Loop            
            END LOOP;

            --Closing the inner cursor
            CLOSE csr_innner_create_evnt_log;

        --Closing the outer Loop            
        END LOOP;

        --Closing the outer cursor
        CLOSE csr_outer_create_evnt_log;

END $Event_Log_Creation_Code$;
```

The ERROR when I run the code:

> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR:  record "rec_tbls" has no field "tbl_column"
>
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT concat('INSERT INTO EventLog_Main
>   (case_id, activity, lifecycle, time_stamp)
>                     VALUES (',rec_tbls.hadm_id,',''',tbl_column,''',''',life_cycle,''',',rec_tbls.tbl_column,');')"
>
> PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 47 at assignment
>
> ********** Error **********

Comment: I understand that "tbl_column" does not exist as a column in "Admissions" table. However, the VALUE of "tbl_column" contains the column name in "Admissions" table. I need help how to use that as parameter to get the value from "rec_tbls" RECORD. Thank you.

Comment: If you are opening "inner" cursor several times in the "outer" cursor in the loop, then you are manually doing an inner join in the loop instead using one SQL query with an inner join. This is a code smell and antipattern - your procedure will be terrible slow. I recomend you to throw this code out and start from scratch. Do a single SELECT with simple JOIN and insert a result using INSERT ... SELECT... statement.

Comment: Thanks krokodilko, how do I do that though?

Comment: To me it seems that this can be done with a single `INSERT INTO EventLog_Main (case_id, activity, lifecycle, time_stamp)
SELECT ...
FROM EventLog_Staging es
  join admissions ad ON ????
WHERE eventrole = 'Event';` the relation between `admissions` and `eventlog_staging` isn't clear to me. I think it would be better if you post the full `create table` statement for the tables in question, some sample data and the expected result based on that data.

Comment: You are also trying to put the value of a column name `table_column` into a column named `time_stamp`. That is either an error or you have very strange naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. Here is the structure of the table EventLog_Staging:  tablecatalog  VARCHAR(200) NULL, tableschema  VARCHAR(200) NULL, tablename VARCHAR(200) NULL,columnname   VARCHAR(200) NULL, datatype VARCHAR(200) NULL, eventrole   VARCHAR(200) NULL, lifecycle VARCHAR(200) NULL,
 description VARCHAR(4000)

Comment: An example content for EventLog_Staging table is: {mimic,mimiciii,admissions,admittime,timestamp,event,complete,time of admission}. Basically, it contains all the column names and descriptions of the table 'Admissions'.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, that's where my error happens. You are right, it looks strange that I am assigning table_column into a column named time_stamp but actually, what I am assigning is the "value" of the table_column, whish is the name "admittime"....where it exists as a column name in "Admissions" table. What I am trying to do is combine rec_tbls (RECORD) with tbl_column into: "rec_tbls.tbl_column" with the intent that it will evaluate into: "rec_tbls.admittime" and can be used to query.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect this:    tx :=concat('INSERT INTO EventLog_Main (case_id, activity, lifecycle, time_stamp) VALUES (',rec_tbls.hadm_id, ',''',tbl_column,''',''',life_cycle,''',',rec_tbls,'.', tbl_column,');');  ****THE RESULT IS*****:     
(142345,'admittime','Complete',(12258,10006,142345,"2164-10-23 21:09:00","2164-11-01 17:15:00",,EMERGENCY,"EMERGENCY ROOM ADMIT","HOME HEALTH CARE",Medicare,,CATHOLIC,SEPARATED,"BLACK/AFRICAN AMERICAN","2164-10-23 16:43:00","2164-10-23 23:00:00",SEPSIS,0,1).admittime); Not what I am expecting.

Comment: This is what I am supposed to get: INSERT INTO EventLog_Main (case_id, activity, lifecycle, time_stamp) VALUES (142345,'admittime','Complete', 2164-10-23 21:09:00).